# Similes and Metaphors - are similes a subset of metaphors?

Tags: figures-of-speech, metaphors, simile

I've always been taught that metaphors and similes both draw a parallel between two disparate ideas/thoughts/objects, but that a simile is a more explicit comparison using the word "like" or "is", whereas a metaphor's connection is more implicit. For example, "His injured ankle burned like a hot stove" is a simile, where as, "His injured ankle was a hot stove of pain" is a metaphor.

However, I recently heard a colleague note that similes *are* nothing more than a special kind of metaphor. In other words, all similes are metaphors. This seems to contradict what I was always taught (and [what I've read online](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/grammar-similes-metaphors.aspx), for what that's worth). Can anyone straighten me (or my colleague) out?

Comment: I never can remember whether a simile is like a metaphor or the other way around.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on [Metaphor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor) agrees with your colleague:

> Metaphor also denotes rhetorical figures of speech that achieve their effects via association, comparison or resemblance (e.g., antithesis, hyperbole, metonymy and **simile**, *which are all types of metaphor*).

(emphasis added)

The article cites "The Oxford Companion to the English Language (1992) pp.653–55" as a reference for the above information, but I don't have access to that publication to verify the statement directly.

***Edit:*** Well, it turns out that I *do* have access to that reference. Here it is, from p. 653, paragraph 2:

> **METAPHOR** ... (1) All figures of speech that achieve their effect through association, comparison, and resemblance. Figures like antithesis, hyperbole, metonymy, simile are all species of metaphor.

Comment: My pleasure. I was taught the same rule as you, so I was also surprised by the answer. I'm glad you asked!

Comment: I have to say, I was taught the same as the OQ, but I like this way of looking at it much better.

Comment: Wikipedia has been updated; this is no longer the case... A simile is NOT a metaphor. Case closed, thank you.

Comment: @Bradog: Poe's law in full effect.

Comment: Nice to see that a couple of edits on Wikipedia can change the English language.

Comment: @PhillipKregg: always check the references

Comment: @e.James I'm not entirely familiar with the editing process on Wikipedia, but it makes me wonder why the edit to remove that information was approved since the reference is a reliable source.

Comment: Sorry folks, but Wikipedia is not recognized as a credible source in academia.