# Is "he runs like a cheetah" a kind of metaphor?

Tags: metaphors

To make a metaphor about somebody's running speed, should we say "he is a cheetah" or "he runs like a cheetah"? Why?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/similes-and-metaphors-are-similes-a-subset-of-metaphors

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"He is a cheetah" is indeed a [metaphor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor), as in fact he is not a cheetah.

"He runs like a cheetah" is more precisely a [simile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simile), even if he does not copy every part of the cheetah's style of running, because of the explicit comparison using *like*.

Both suggest he is fast. Either will probably convey your message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I actually didn't understand the difference between metaphor and simile. I'm gonna ask it in another question. :)

Comment: @Saeed Neamati: A simile uses an explicit comparison with words such as "like" or "as".

Comment: Whereas a metaphor says that thing A "is" thing B, even though it literally is not. "He is like a cheetah" is a simile. "He is a cheetah" is a metaphor. A simile is like a metaphor. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think we can safely say both "**He is a cheetah**" and "**He runs like a cheetah**" are metaphoric.

The first more so, since presumably "he" is a human being. But he doesn't run on all fours like a cheetah (or as fast, if we're honest!), so he's only metaphorically running *like* one.

If OP wants to "make" a metaphor, he can use the first form. It will have been said many times before, I'm sure, but I certainly wouldn't call it a cliche.

The second form has probably been used even more often, so if OP only wants to "use" a metaphor, that may be the one to go for.

Comment: "He runs like a cheetah" is not metaphoric as it is a comparison between two different things (man and cheetah) rather than a direct application of of man to cheetah. The definition of metaphor states "a [metaphor is a] figure of speech in which a word or phrase is applied to an object or action to which it is not literally applicable."

Comment: @gud with Inglesh: Yeah yeah. As every schoolboy is taught: *"A simile is **like** something else; a metaphor **is** something else"*. But once you go beyond the schoolboy level, most would say that [similes are metaphors](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rKX7qcQerLcC&pg=PA29&dq=%22similes+are+metaphors%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Zog2VJflEo3Y7AaVVw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22similes%20are%20metaphors%22&f=false) anyway. And even a schoolboy should know that adjectival *metaphoric* covers both types of usage (more specifically than *figurative*).

Comment: I disagree, they are both analogies, however, metaphors and similes are different by definition.

Comment: @gud with Inglesh This string has just resurfaced. >> The definition of metaphor states 'an expression, often found in literature, that describes a person or object by referring to something that is considered to have similar characteristics to that person or object'. [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/metaphor) as opposed to ODO (Now Lexico). OED will no doubt contain both the narrower and the broader definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Both are analogies. "He is a cheetah is a metaphor" and  "He runs like a cheetah" is a simile. Either are acceptable; it is a matter of style.