# What kind of rhetoric is "The computer runs as fast as a rocket."?

Tags: rhetoric

At first sight I would say it is a metaphor, but after some thought I'm not sure anymore. The parallel is not so exact between the two objects, since the speed of a computer usually refers to the response speed(or more technically, measured in terms of frequency), while the speed of a rocket usually refers to the traveling speed. A more conventional metaphor is like "The boy runs as fast as a rocket.", so what is "The computer runs as fast as a rocket."?

Comment: I think writers don't have to be computer engineers to distinguish between the two types of speeds.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "broken metaphor". Rockets don't run. /thread

Comment: It's a metaphor/ simile, simple and straight. Neither really runs. Both 'run' in their own way. The use of 'run' is a smart choice of a word that collocates with both 'computer' and 'rocket', though in a subtly difference sense.

Comment: @RegDwighт: what's the meaning of "broken metaphor"? Does it mean "lousy metaphor"?

Comment: No, not just lousy; actually broken. *Rocket* doesn't collocate with *run* anywhere as well as Kris would have you believe. It collocates with *fly* or *move*. A rocket can run *out of fuel*, at best. For computers, on the other hand, *run* is *the* verb of choice. Running is all they do. So saying "The computer runs as fast as a rocket" is on par with saying "Christopher Lee keeps making films as fast as a rocket", or "My wife buys shoes as fast as a rocket" or "I drink vodka as fast as a rocket". It's not lousy; it's nonsense.

Comment: I agree. Rockets don't run. Even if they did, it wouldn't be a good comparison.  For example you probably wouldn't say "The computer runs as fast as a train" because they are different meanings of the word 'run'.

Comment: @Chasly: I can't find a link to what I'm sure was a Monty Python skit, but being UK you should know it anyway. Only the stooge is nonplussed by [*Bet she goes like a train, does she?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22goes+like+a+train+does+she%22) (Nudge, nudge. Say no MORE! :)

Comment: Nudge, nudge, wink, wink, say no more! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7HycFnH26U   I must admit that came to mind when I was commenting!

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the fact that you're not talking about literal speed matters. In fact, you could say that the use of the term speed in the context of computers is a metaphor itself - but this dooes not affect the comparison with the rocket.

Regarding the comparison with the rocket: both your examples - *the computer runs as fast as a rocket* and *the boy runs as fast as a rocket* are the same, but they are not metaphors. They are in fact **similes**, due to the use of the comparative phrase *as fast as*. Had you said *the computer **is** a rocket*, that would have been a metaphor, though arguably not a very good one!

Comment: I agree; rockets are fast, so is this computer. That said, if I wanted to make the comparison, I'd probably phrase it more like this: _"The computer runs fast, like a rocket,"_ or maybe even, _"The computer runs rocket-fast."_

Comment: Just one doubt, isn't simile a special kind of metaphor? This is what I learnt from this post  <a href="http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/similes-and-metaphors-are-similes-a-subset-of-metaphors"></a>

Comment: @JiaYiyang apparently so. Most of us, however, were taught that similes and metaphors are different and had teachers frown on us when we confused them.

Comment: @JiaYiyang, interesting, I've never come across similes defined as a type of metaphor. Either way, simile is a more accurate description, as it is more specific.

Comment: Computers are rockets is a great metaphor!