# Is this a simile or a metaphor?

Tags: simile

'Houses sprouted like mushroom colonies'

I am not sure if this is a simile or a metaphor. Please help. Ty!

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: A simile is *like* a metaphor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Similes and Metaphors - are similes a subset of metaphors?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/similes-and-metaphors-are-similes-a-subset-of-metaphors)

Comment: It's a simile (because of *like*). But a simile is also a type of metaphor. So, it's both.

Comment: And a smile is like a simile, only without the "i".